# Distribution of prime gaps - is it an unsolved problem?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-gaps, distribution-of-primes

Numerical experiments show the distribution of prime gaps conforms to some quite firm constraints.

The following plot visualises these constraints - it shows the log of the count of prime gaps against gaps.

**Question:** I can't find much information on how this distribution is explained by properties of primes. **Is this because it is genuinely an area of mathematics that hasn't been explored, or yielded results?**

I have looked through many of the standard texts (Stopple, Edwards, Apostol, Derbyshire,...) and done internet searches for university course content (indicating the study of prime gaps is well established) - but I have found very little, or nothing. The content I can find is a few blogs or YouTube videos which touch on this question but don't explain it.

I am not university trained in mathematics so I may be unaware of the state of the art, so apologies if the answer is (1) obvious, or (2) well known as an open question in mathematics.

Note: Is this question more difficult because it is essentially about the additive properties of primes rather than the multiplicative properties.

[image]

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap).  Summary: much is conjectured, not much is proven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As usual for open problems about primes) the first answer is the random model for the primes.

The simplest model for the gap $g(n)=p_{n+1}-p_n$ is that it follows approximately an exponential distribution of parameter $1-\frac2{\log n}$, following from that the probability that $p_n+2j$ is not prime is about $1-\frac2{\log (p_n+2j)}\approx 1-\frac2{\log n}$ so that

$$Pr(g(n)=2k)\approx (1-\frac2{\log n})^{k-1} \frac2{\log n}$$ And thus your curve is not surprising at all:

when looking at the gaps for $n\le N$ then most $\log n$ are $\approx \log N$ so you expect about $(1-\frac2{\log N})^{k-1} \frac{2N}{\log N} $ gaps of size $2k$ ie. a $\log$ proportion $\approx (k-1) \log (1-\frac2{\log N})-\log\log N$

Comment: hi @reuns could you explain why the probably that $p_n + 2j$ is not prime is approx $1-\frac{2}{\log (p_n+2j)}$, and what is the relationship between $j$ and $n$. thanks

Comment: The PNT says that $\pi(x)\sim \sum_{2n\le x} \frac{2}{\log n}$, the random model for the primes says that $2n$ is prime with a probability $2/\log n$ and that those "random variables" are (approximatively) independent for different $n$. This is just a model, not the truth, but it gives surprising good predictions in a lot of different settings.

Comment: Hi @reuns - I am almost there but not quite. The probability $n$ is prime is $1/\log(n)$ from the approx observation of prime density, and reflected in the PNT. How do we go from this to $2/\log(n)$ ?

Comment: Just discarding the even numbers, because the prime gaps are even.

Comment: sorry @reuns I'm not good enough at the algebra to see how to get from discarding the evens to $2/\log(n)$.

Comment: $\pi(x)\sim \sum_{2n\le x} \frac{2}{\log n}$

Comment: The probability that $n$ is prime is $1/\log n$, the probability that $n$ is prime knowing that it is even is $0$, the probability knowing that it is odd is $2/\log n$, that's the model.

Comment: Thanks that helps. Next question: why is $1-\frac2{\log (p_n+2j)}\approx 1-\frac2{\log n}$?

Comment: For (obvious?) and PNT reasons we assume that $n$ is large so $\log p_n \approx \log n$ and we assume $j$ is small compared to $p_n$.

Comment: hi @reuns - I can't seem to get my head around this. For any $n$ the corresponding $p_n$ is larger, and on average $p_n$ is $n\cdot\log(n)$ from PNT. So taking logs gives us $\log{p_n} \sim \log n + \log \log(n)$ ? Do we discard loglog because it is slowly growing? It still diverges to infinity so imho it can't be discarded.

Comment: I've tried to recount a simpler version of your idea (credited), would appreciate your comments of you have time. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4106492/improving-simple-probabilistic-prime-model-to-model-prime-gaps